# How does Thanos pull metrics from PushGateway?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-pushgateway, thanos

I have a metric: `my_metric{date="", checker="", host=""}`

For some business reason, the `date` label may be updated everyday. That means, suppose I have two metrics on `2023-10-31`, like this:

```
my_metric{date="2023-10-31", checker="fileChecker", host="server_01"}    1
my_metric{date="2023-10-31", checker="dirChecker", host="server_02"}     2
```

Then the second day, my `fileChecker.sh` cronjob checks the status of some target files, and my metrics look like this:

```
my_metric{date="2023-10-31", checker="fileChecker", host="server_01"}    1
my_metric{date="2023-10-31", checker="dirChecker", host="server_02"}     2
my_metric{date="2023-11-01", checker="fileChecker", host="server_01"}    0
```

Now I use `PushGateway` to collect these metrics from my server, and let `Thanos` to pull them from the `PushGateway`. And my intention is to let `Thanos` be a remote storage.

To do this, I set `PushGateway's grouping key` as `{checker, host}`. I know that because the same `checker` from the same `host` will form the same `grouping key`, so `PushGateway` ***overwrites*** my metrics.

I suppose these metrics inside PushGateway should be like this:

```
my_metric{date="2023-10-31", checker="dirChecker", host="server_02"}     2
my_metric{date="2023-11-01", checker="fileChecker", host="server_01"}    0
```

**But** if I config Thanos to pull metrics from PushGateway every 1 minute or anyway less than 1 day. The metric

`my_metric{date="2023-10-31", checker="fileChecker", host="server_01"}    1`

should be stored inside `Thanos`. So even if it is overwritten by the same grouping key at the second day 2023-11-01, the overwritten should **only** happen inside `PushGateway` but not inside `Thanos`. However, when I query this metric on `Grafana`, and set data source as `Thanos`, I find it is not return this metric.

Does anyone know why this happens? I was thinking it must be the problem with same grouping key but if i understand it right, this should not happen in a remote storage Thanos.